# OnePlus 6t connecting to Mac

Tags: android, react-native, adb, oneplus6t

I am developing an app with React Native. Thus far, Ive been testing on a iPhone, but naturally I want to test on an android device as well. I borrowed a OnePlus 6t, but I am having troubles connecting this device to my Macbook (pro 16" 2019). I've enabled developer mode and switched USB debugging on. Still my Mac does not recognize the device, even when I do `adb devices`. Any experience with this?

One sidenote is that the USB-C socket of the phone seems to be worn out, since my cable will not "click" into the device. The device is charging when sticking the cable in the phone though, so there seems to be some kind of connection.

Thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0):

I asked for the original cable, and using that it worked. Seems that USB-C is not as universal as I thought.